# Deploy iOS App on Tester Device. App doesn't contain some images

Tags: ios, image, ipad, deployment, ios-simulator

i have create a file ipa for my tester device. When i upload file to my iTunes library and i install it on my device (iPad) there are not problems but if i run the same app on iPad and on xcode simulator the screed are not the same. The screen on iPad doesn't contain png images.

These are the screen:

XCODE SIMULATOR
[image]

IPAD
[image]

What is the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The image names are case sensitive on device, but not in simulator. Check to see if the names are right.